# Chain vs seatstay with a 50T Chainring - BMX frame

Tags: chain, frames, chainring, bmx

I plan to put a 50T chainring on my bmx but I am afraid to have an interference between the chain and the frame.

Does anybody know what is the critical distance between the seatstay and the chain so as to have no inteferences between the two during riding ?

Comment: 1mm should do it

Comment: I'm curious as to why the chain and seat stay would make contact? A larger chainring should not move it any closer to the seat stay, assuming the chainline is unmodified than the chain should be routed very similar. I would be more worried about the chainring being close to the chainstay if the ring size has increased.

Comment: @Nate . The fact is that I have a small seat tube (around 160mm). If I increase the diameter of the chainring, the chain will come very close to the seat stay (because the SS is very low due to the small seat tube). I wouldn't had have this problem if the seat tube had been longer.

Comment: No idea as to an actual number sorry, but if you measure a 50T chainring, cut a circle from cardboard and tape it to your bike, then hold any chain up where you think it would run.  There should be minimal chain bounce on the top length while peddling.  A mock-up like this will let you test without wasting money.  You'll also see the ground clearance/breakover angles change, and whether the chainring clears the chainstay too.

Comment: @Greg.D Right on, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It depends on your frame and the stays. 50t might be a bit big. The sprocket could catch the frame Old/Mid school bmx's generally had chainrings of around 42t/44t, (with a freewheel of generally 16t) but the as the gear ratio has come down since the inception of cassette hubs 25:9 is pretty much the standard ratio and modern frames/stays have been designed with this in mind. Also what cranks are you using? The majority of bmx specific cranks are spline drive or secure the sprocket onto the crank arm with a single bolt, and don't use a spider like road/mtb bikes. .....50:9 ratio "shut up legs!"

Comment: @Hitchmo In fact it's the opposite tendance in bmx racing (sorry, i didn't say that it was for bmx racing). The goal is to increase the chainring and the freewheel like 50x 19 or 18 espescially in world cup circus where the tracks are speeder. The problems is if you increase the diameter of the chainring and the free wheel and you decrease the high of the seat-tube (to low the gravity point) you will have an interference probleme between the SS and the chain.

Comment: @Greg.D  This question is 22 months old now.  Are you able to add an answer sharing what you did, how you found it?  Specially helpful for other searchers is what worked for you and what didn't work.   This is permitted and encouraged by SE.